# Solution of a Riccati ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integrating-factor

I have the following ODE:

$$\frac{d y}{d x}=y^2-(A \csc^2 x+B^2 \sin^2 x-C)$$

where $A,B,C$ are constants.

Can one come up with an appropriate integrating factor to make it exact?

Comment: May I ask where did you find such an equation ? It seems to be very difficult.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici It came up while trying to solve for a superpotential in SUSY QM.

Comment: You cross-posted (almost) the same question on MO [Solution of a Riccati ODE](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/301428/solution-of-a-riccati-ode) without mentioning it. This is considered a bad practice. Incidentally, there is an answer on MO.