# Solution of a Riccati ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following ODE:

$$\frac{d y}{d x}=y^2-(A \csc^2 x+B^2 \sin^2 x-C)$$

where $A,B,C$ are constants.

Can one come up with an appropriate integrating factor to make it exact?

I have been trying various ways such as change of variable: $y=z \sqrt{A \csc^2 x + B^2 \sin ^2 x-C}$, but none of them seem to work.

**Edit**:

As pointed out in the comment, I am sorry to not have linked my duplicate question in MSE in the first place. I had already asked the same question in MSE, and as I was not getting any response I thought of asking here.

Duplicate question in MSE:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2800133/solution-of-a-riccati-ode

Answer (score 1):

The Maple 2018.0 command

```
dsolve(diff(y(x), x) = y(x)^2-A*csc(x)^2-B^2*sin(x)^2+C);
```

outputs

> `{y(x) = (1/2)*(4*cos(x)^2*HeunCPrime(0, 1/2, (1/2)*(4*A+1)^(1/2), -(1/4)*B^2, 3/8+(1/4)*B^2+(1/4)*A+(1/4)*C, cos(x)^2)*_C1+4*cos(x)*HeunCPrime(0, -1/2, (1/2)*(4*A+1)^(1/2), -(1/4)*B^2, 3/8+(1/4)*B^2+(1/4)*A+(1/4)*C, cos(x)^2)+2*HeunC(0, 1/2, (1/2)*(4*A+1)^(1/2), -(1/4)*B^2, 3/8+(1/4)*B^2+(1/4)*A+(1/4)*C, cos(x)^2)*_C1)*sin(x)/(cos(x)*HeunC(0, 1/2, (1/2)*(4*A+1)^(1/2), -(1/4)*B^2, 3/8+(1/4)*B^2+(1/4)*A+(1/4)*C, cos(x)^2)*_C1+HeunC(0, -1/2, (1/2)*(4*A+1)^(1/2), -(1/4)*B^2, 3/8+(1/4)*B^2+(1/4)*A+(1/4)*C, cos(x)^2))+(1/2)*((-(4*A+1)^(1/2)*_C1-_C1)*HeunC(0, 1/2, (1/2)*(4*A+1)^(1/2), -(1/4)*B^2, 3/8+(1/4)*B^2+(1/4)*A+(1/4)*C, cos(x)^2)*cos(x)^2+(-(4*A+1)^(1/2)-1)*HeunC(0, -1/2, (1/2)*(4*A+1)^(1/2), -(1/4)*B^2, 3/8+(1/4)*B^2+(1/4)*A+(1/4)*C, cos(x)^2)*cos(x))/((cos(x)*HeunC(0, 1/2, (1/2)*(4*A+1)^(1/2), -(1/4)*B^2, 3/8+(1/4)*B^2+(1/4)*A+(1/4)*C, cos(x)^2)*_C1+HeunC(0, -1/2, (1/2)*(4*A+1)^(1/2), -(1/4)*B^2, 3/8+(1/4)*B^2+(1/4)*A+(1/4)*C, cos(x)^2))*sin(x))}`

in terms of [Heun function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heun_function).

Comment: So, Maple is, in this respect, better.  Mathematica 11.3.0.0., after        DSolve[y'[x] == (y[x])^2 - A (Csc[x])^2 + B (Sin[x])^2 + C, y, x], gives the answer "Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information."